# Change colour on row in one sheet if same value exists in second sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet named `Skruvdragare` where cells B1-B500 contain serial numbers like: `123456789`, `987654321` etc and a second sheet `Låda 1` in which I will also put in some serial numbers (not necessarily the same numbers as in the `Skruvdragare` sheet).

If I put in a serial number, anywhere in `Låda 1`, which exists in `Skruvdragare` I want the row for this serial number to turn to red background and white text in the `Skruvdragare` sheet.

Comment: No i want entire rows in i Skruvdragare to be formatted based on values such as 123456789 being found in Låda 1, if it also exists in Skruvdragare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Conditional Formatting for this. But, as I've learned right now, the formula must not contain references to other sheets...so we work around this limitation by putting the formula into an auxiliary column in sheet2:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($A1,sheet1!$A$1:$A$500,0)))
```

and the conditional format just contains the formula

```
=$D1
```

if the aux column was "D". Copy that format to as many cells you like (except for the aux column!).

Comment: Why, an error in the formula, or you are not allowed to add a column in sheet2?

Comment: No, i get no errors or warnings, but i get no result, the colors don't change.

Comment: The result depends on the cells used: put the formula `=NOT(` into cell D1 on sheet2 (please adjust for your own sheet names) and the cond. format on cell A1. If you put a value into A1 which is found on sheet1 in A1:A500 then the format changes.

Comment: OK. lets say i have this on sheet1 in cell A1: 123456789. Now if i put 123456789 in sheet2 (in any A cell)  the cell A1 in sheet1 should change colors. How would this formula look like? Thank you.

Comment: ...and on sheet2, put 123456789 into A1, and the formula into D1. D1 will show TRUE (in your language of course). Then you base the conditional format for A1 on the value of D1: `=D1`. When you change the value of A1, say to 555, D1 becomes FALSE and the formatting disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Please [Define Name](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) of Workbook Scope for `Låda 1`, say `OtherSheet`:

> 1. Select the cell, range of cells, or nonadjacent selections that you want to name.
> 2. Click the **Name** box at the left end of the formula bar.
>
> [image]
>
> Name box
>
> 3. Type the name that you want to use to refer to your selection. Names can be up to 255 characters in length.
> 4. Press ENTER.

Select from Row1 to Row500 in `Skruvdragare` and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(OtherSheet,$B1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill white font, OK, OK.

Comment: What do you mean by this: Please Define Name of Workbook Scope?

Comment: Thank you for all your help guys, but non of this is working form me. Do any of you have an example file for me to download. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, i would now like to take this further. I now have a column in bouth sheets that is called Namn. In skruvdragare this column is empty, but in Låda1 i have a name in this column (the column is G2 by the way). So if a name exists in Låda1 on the same row as a Serienummer that exists in bout sheets then this name should be added in Skruvdragare G2. Sorry i'm not to good at explaining.